# Find Healthcare Data by Geography and Income Level

Tags: data, health, demography

Is anybody aware of a data source for healthcare related data (number of people covered, type, etc.) for any geography (looking for USA) that can also be broken down by income level?

I've tried ArcGIS Community Analyst but they don't seem to have any healthcare data aside from expenditures from a market potential standpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Census Bureau provides this type of information. However, the amount of specificity you are asking about is more than what they are willing to provide (for privacy reasons). The closest table is [B27015](http://factfinder2.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/12_5YR/B27015/0400000US12.14000) which covers general insurance status by household income category at the Census Tract level. Oh, and for reference, the Census Tract level is the lowest geography that will be available, and with any estimation at a small geography, make sure the margin of error is reasonable.

If you want specific counts of the population with a specific type of health insurance, you have options which include: [Employer-Based](http://factfinder2.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/12_5YR/C27004/0400000US12.14000), [Direct-Purchase](http://factfinder2.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/12_5YR/C27005/0400000US12.14000), [Medicare alone](http://factfinder2.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/12_5YR/C27006/0400000US12.14000), [Medicaid alone](http://factfinder2.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/12_5YR/C27007/0400000US12.14000), [Tricare/Military](http://factfinder2.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/12_5YR/C27008/0400000US12.14000), and [VA](http://factfinder2.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/12_5YR/C27009/0400000US12.14000). You could even try a [table](http://factfinder2.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/12_5YR/C27010/0400000US12.14000) which examines the population of people with discrete combinations of health insurances.

If you are interested there are geodatabases (ArcGIS 10.1 or Later) that have the information joined to shapefiles [here](ftp://ftp.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER_DP/2012ACS/).

Answer (score 2):

The only area in the US I could find is based in California by the [Healthcare Workforce Development Division](http://www.oshpd.ca.gov/hwdd/Research_Policy_Planning_GIS.html) (HWDD). They collect GIS data in terms of:

- Medical Service Study Areas
- Health Professional Shortage Areas
- Medically Underserved Areas / Medically Underserved Population
- And other miscellaneous data

The site contains shapefiles, PDF maps and Excel files which look into and analyse the following:

- Population density
- Provider-to-population ratios
- Poverty levels
- Public health indicators for eligibility to receive federal assistance

Hope this helps.